Space between enumerated/itemized items
I want to increase the spacing between the items listed. Any help in getting this done is much appareciated.
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{ll}
\text { \textbf{(a).} }~  a_{0}=\dfrac{1}{2 L} \int_{-L}^{L} f(x) ~d x \\

\vspace{3 mm}

\text { \textbf{(b).} }~  a_{n}=\dfrac{1}{L} \int_{-L}^{L} f(x) \cos \dfrac{n \pi x}{L} ~d x \\

\bigskip

\text { \textbf{(c).} }~ \displaystyle b_{n}=\dfrac{1}{L} \int_{-L}^{L} f(x) \sin \dfrac{n \pi x}{L} ~d x 
\end{array}
\end{equation


Why not use \\[x pt]?

Just out of idle curiosity: Why do you define the array environment to have 2 columns when you use just one column?

Here are a couple ways I'm familiar with:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{4} % to change spacing of every row by some factor

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{ll}
\text { \textbf{(a).} }~  a_{0}=\dfrac{1}{2 L} \int_{-L}^{L} f(x) ~d x \\[3mm] % to add extra spacing for one row

%\vspace{3 mm}

\text { \textbf{(b).} }~  a_{n}=\dfrac{1}{L} \int_{-L}^{L} f(x) \cos \dfrac{n \pi x}{L} ~d x \\

%\bigskip

\text { \textbf{(c).} }~ \displaystyle b_{n}=\dfrac{1}{L} \int_{-L}^{L} f(x) \sin \dfrac{n \pi x}{L} ~d x 
\end{array}
\end{equation}

\end{document}


I suggest you use an actual enumerate environment with a custom label.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}  % for \dfrac macro
\usepackage{enumitem} % easily customize enumerate and itemize envrionments
\usepackage{xcolor}   % for \textcolor macro
\begin{document}

\textcolor{red}{before}
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{ll}
\text { \textbf{(a).} }~  a_{0}=\dfrac{1}{2 L} \int_{-L}^{L} f(x) ~d x \\

\vspace{3 mm}

\text { \textbf{(b).} }~  a_{n}=\dfrac{1}{L} \int_{-L}^{L} f(x) \cos \dfrac{n \pi x}{L} ~d x \\

\bigskip

\text { \textbf{(c).} }~ \displaystyle b_{n}=\dfrac{1}{L} \int_{-L}^{L} f(x) \sin \dfrac{n \pi x}{L} ~d x 
\end{array}
\end{equation}

\bigskip
\textcolor{red}{after}
\begin{equation}
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\bfseries(\alph*).]
\item $a_{0}=\dfrac{1}{2 L} \int_{-L}^{L} f(x) \,dx $

\item $a_{n}=\dfrac{1}{L} \int_{-L}^{L} f(x) \cos \dfrac{n \pi x}{L} \,dx $

\item $\displaystyle b_{n}=\frac{1}{L} \int_{-L}^{L} f(x) \sin \frac{n \pi x}{L} \,dx$ 
\end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}
\end{equation}

\end{document}

